# Change default locale in Magento 2 not working

Tags: magento2

I installed Magento 2, and then installed a theme but the CSS and JS does not work.

I ran the command: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

But when I visit the frontend it can not find the CSS or JS. I think it is a problem because I do not have en_US locale as default and the theme only comes with this.

So I go back to admin in: `Stores > Configuration > General` to try and change the default locale, but the dropdown is grayed out.

I tried every possible store view but I can't change it back to en_US.

How do I fix this?

Comment: change to developer mode

Comment: Changing to developer mode solved my problem, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US -f
```